# Deshabilitar scrollbar - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa de prueba que inserta una entrada al dar doble click en un ítem especifico de una listbox. Quiero que al insertar la entrada me inhabilite el deslizamiento vertical. Logré deshabilitar el deslizamiento mediante la rueda del mouse, pero no se como hacerlo cuando presiono la scrollbar y la muevo. Alguna idea?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(height = 400, width = 200)

def funcion(event):
    def fijar_posicion(event):
        posicion = fracciones
        if widget.yview() != posicion:
            widget.yview_moveto(posicion[0])
        scroll_y.set(posicion[0], posicion[1])

    widget = event.widget

    # Genera las coordenadas para la entrada
    item = widget.curselection()[0]
    alto_celda = 16
    cantidad_items = len(widget.get(0, tk.END))
    fraccion_item = 1/cantidad_items
    fracciones = widget.yview()
    item_inicial = fracciones[0]/fraccion_item
    diferencia_hasta_item = item - item_inicial
    coor_listbox_x = widget.winfo_x()
    coor_listbox_y = widget.winfo_y()

    # Fijamos el deslizamiento vertical
    root.bind("<MouseWheel>", fijar_posicion)

    # Crea la entrada
    entrada = tk.Entry(root)
    entrada.place(x = coor_listbox_x + 2, y = coor_listbox_y + alto_celda*diferencia_hasta_item + 2, width = 100 - 4, height = alto_celda)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 100, height = 300)

scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll_y.place(x = 10 + 100, y = 10, height = 300)

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)
scroll_y.config(command = listbox.yview)

for i in range(0, 30):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, i)

root.bind_all('<Double-Button-1>', funcion)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay una forma nativa de deshabilitar una scrollbar, pero lo que si podemos hacer es crear una función propia que envuelva a `listbox.yview` y pasarla en su lugar a `command`. Dicha función solo debe llamar a `listbox.yview` cuando queramos que el scroll esté activo:

```
def _listbox_yview(*args, **kwargs):
    if not listbox.fijar_posicion:
        listbox.yview(*args, **kwargs)

scroll_y.config(command = _listbox_yview)
```

Para deshabilitar el scroll del ratón directamente sobre la ListBox, existe una alternativa muy simple, basta con asociar los eventos de la rueda del ratón a una fucnión propia que se encargue de retornar "break" (detener la propagación del evento) cuando el scroll esté desactivado.

Por último, para especificar cuando el scroll debe estar o no activo podemos crear un nuevo atributo de instancia de nuestro listbox asociada a un valor boleano:

```
listbox.fijar_posicion = False
```

El código completo podría quedar:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(height = 400, width = 200)

def funcion(event):
    def liberar_entry(event):
        widget.fijar_posicion = False
        widget.config(state="normal") # Habilitar listbox 
        event.widget.place_forget()   # Eliminar Entry

    widget = event.widget
    widget.fijar_posicion = True
    widget.config(state="disabled")

    # Genera las coordenadas para la entrada
    item = widget.curselection()[0]
    alto_celda = 16
    cantidad_items = len(widget.get(0, tk.END))
    fraccion_item = 1/cantidad_items
    fracciones = widget.yview()
    item_inicial = fracciones[0]/fraccion_item
    diferencia_hasta_item = item - item_inicial
    coor_listbox_x = widget.winfo_x()
    coor_listbox_y = widget.winfo_y()

    # Crea la entrada
    entrada = tk.Entry(root)
    entrada.place(x = coor_listbox_x + 2,
                  y = coor_listbox_y + alto_celda * diferencia_hasta_item + 2,
                  width = 100 - 4,
                  height = alto_celda
                  )
    entrada.focus_set()
    entrada.bind("<Return>", liberar_entry)

def _on_scroll(event):
    if listbox.fijar_posicion:
        return "break"

def _listbox_yview(*args, **kwargs):
    if not listbox.fijar_posicion:
        listbox.yview(*args, **kwargs)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.fijar_posicion = False
listbox.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 100, height = 300)
listbox.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_scroll) # rueda ratón
listbox.bind("<Button-4>", _on_scroll)   # rueda ratón en sistemas x11 
listbox.bind("<Button-5>", _on_scroll)   # rueda ratón en sistemas x11 
listbox.bind("<B1-Leave>", _on_scroll)   # desplazamiento automático

scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll_y.place(x = 10 + 100, y = 10, height = 300)
listbox.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)
scroll_y.config(command = _listbox_yview)



for i in range(0, 30):
    listbox.insert(tk.END, i)

listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', funcion)
root.mainloop()
```

Hay que especificar bajo que situaciones se debe liberar el Entry y volver a habilitar el scroll y el listbox, en este caso lo hago cuando se pulsa <kbd>Enter</kbd> en el `Entry`, pero esto puede modificarse según necesidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]